# Travel from domestic- international (Japan) with Air China in Beijing

Tags: air-travel, transit, air-china

I will have a transfer with Air China in Beijing Terminal 3, from a domestic flight China to International flight Osaka... I am not sure but I will probably need to check in again my baggage. Someone have a experience? And if yes, can help me about the procedure?

Comment: Could you clarify the airlines in question?